# Method not allowed on payment callback in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I wrote some code that handles the callback request from my payment service. But I get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. No message.

Here is my controller :

```
    if(isset($_POST['State']) && $_POST['State'] == "OK") {

        $soapclient = new soapclient('https://verify.sep.ir/Payments/ReferencePayment.asmx?WSDL');
        $res        = $soapclient->VerifyTransaction($_POST['RefNum'], $MerchantCode);

        if( $res <= 0 )
        {
            // Transaction Failed
            echo "Transaction Failed";
        } else {
            // Transaction Successful
            echo "Transaction Successful";
            echo "Ref : {$_POST['RefNum']}<br />";
            echo "Res : {$res}<br />";
        }
    } else {
        // Transaction Failed
        echo "Transaction Failed";
    }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Hi, please show us all the code for controller and how your route is declared for the callback url.

Comment: @KFoobar It's completed code and i define Get route in routes for my callback

Comment: I can't be the complete code since the class and method declaration is missing. Without the full code, it pretty hard to help you since all we can do is to guess whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you used the `GET` method for the route, update it to a `POST` and will be working fine since the API seems to expect that.

Comment: i tried to change to post method but  a get page expired message (i think because i don't have csrf field)

Comment: You can add your route to list of exclusions on the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware. It's available under `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`. Read more on https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: unfortunately i can't add exclusion because my url pattern like : `http://site/cart/abcdefghijk/verifypayment`  what do you suggest?

Comment: do a wildcard after `cart`.